# Can I make a P-trap with 45° elbows?

Tags: plumbing, pvc

Can I make a P-trap for 2 inch PVC out of a 90° and 2 45° elbows? The 2 45° elbows would be arranged in an `S` pattern.

[image: diagram of p trap]

Comment: The major issue with that idea is that you cannot easily disassemble it to fetch out something that may have accidentally been dropped down the drain. Commercial P-Traps are made with a coupler joint that can be opened by removing a plastic ring nut.

Comment: from the fact that home depot sells a p trap that one is not able to disassemble http://www.homedepot.com/p/2-in-PVC-DWV-Hub-x-Hub-P-Trap-C4885HD2/100342868 i think that would not be the problem

Comment: The issue (as far as the code is concerned) is not accessibility, but the depth of the trap seal. You can make your our p-traps from fittings so long as they maintain the required trap seal. See @Tester101's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. That will likely not pass inspection.  Most codes require a trap seal of 2-4", which you will not get with a 45.

Trap seal is measured from the top of the trap bend, to the trap weir.

[image: trap depth]

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very careful with that line of thinking. The combination of a short and long leg in a drain creates a siphon. In the case of your photo, if the section heading off left makes a short turn downwards gravity may empty the trap during heavy use leaving you with a wonderful open connection to the sewer.

While cleanout isn't the major issue, it is a consideration too. At least in a trap without a cleanout you know where children's toys and wedding rings are. That setup looks like it would happily pass hairballs, grease, and anything else further down the pipe. Not only will blockages be tougher to clear when they're far away, they'll also stop multiple drains from working. There's nothing quite like a sink that causes the toilet and washing machine to overflow.